# How to use another ioc container with mef?

Tags: wpf, architecture, prism, mef, autofac

i am using mef with prism. i can use mef because i like the export, import, metadata attributes and mostly aggregate cagalog usage. so i want to use mef with prism project.

In my plan, my solution projects must be use autofac or castle windsor ioc container and i implement like that except prism project(wpf). In case, i am not prefer to use autofac or castle windsor instead of mef's default di/ioc but too many alternative usage of personal experimantals are failed.

Is there a any stable sample project i can use? I want to change only ioc of mef with all mef functionalty.

My classic mef bootstrapper code is bellow
    Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting
    Imports Microsoft.Practices.Prism.MefExtensions
    Imports Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation

```
Public Class Bootstrapper2
    Inherits MefBootstrapper

    Protected Overrides Sub ConfigureContainer()
        MyBase.ConfigureContainer()

        Dim ag As New AggregateCatalog()
        ag.Catalogs.Add(New AssemblyCatalog(GetType(Bootstrapper2).Assembly))
        ag.Catalogs.Add(New DirectoryCatalog("..\..\modules\", "Prism.Sample.Modules.*.dll"))

        Me.AggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(ag)
    End Sub


    Protected Overrides Function CreateShell() As DependencyObject
        Dim s As Shell = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Of Shell)()

        Return s
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub InitializeShell()
        Application.Current.MainWindow = Shell()
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Shell's code is bellow:
    Imports System.ComponentModel.Composition

```
<Export()> _
Public Class Shell

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    <Import(AllowRecomposition:=False)> _
    Public Property ViewModel() As ShellViewModel
        Get
            Return CType(Me.DataContext, ShellViewModel)
        End Get
        Set(value As ShellViewModel)
            Me.DataContext = value
        End Set
    End Property


End Class
```

Now, everythings working like an expected.

modified/overrided bootstrapper's ConfigureServiceLocator() method is bellow.

```
Private autofacBuilder As New Autofac.ContainerBuilder

Protected Overrides Sub ConfigureServiceLocator()
    Dim autofacContainer = autofacBuilder.Build()
    Dim autofacSL = New Prism.AutofacExtension.AutofacServiceLocatorAdapter(autofacContainer)

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Function() autofacSL)
End Sub
```

then i have got an too many resolving exception for example:
exception message:
    Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type RegionAdapterMappings, key "".

Prism or another code base trying to resolve IRegionAdapterMappings from the servicelocator but currentservice locator not knowns what is this.Because mef is allready registered this types((ConfigureContainer) before CreateServiceLocator.

So, then i trying to add mef's aggregate catalog to register autofac container with Autofac.Integration.Mef project like this:

```
Private autofacBuilder As New Autofac.ContainerBuilder

Protected Overrides Sub ConfigureServiceLocator()
    autofacBuilder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(Me.AggregateCatalog)

    Dim autofacContainer = autofacBuilder.Build()
    Dim autofacSL = New Prism.AutofacExtension.AutofacServiceLocatorAdapter(autofacContainer)

    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Function() autofacSL)
End Sub
```

Then i have got a diffrent exception: IServiceLocator not registered etc...

I have not a complately solutions for changing mef's ioc container because its own container types and uses her own extensibility. Tried to use Autofac.Integration.Mef but maybe it not future compatible. maybe not developep when mef' new releases.

I am a big blakc hole i think. Is there a any way can't i see?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you reformulate your issue a bit better and provide some illustration code?

Comment: tried AutofacBootstrapper and it works but i dont want to use them because i am not sure to supports all mef features at the future.